# Check whether NSURLConnection failed or not

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLConnection in order to get some xml files from a web server. When the server is down, I want to inform the user. I cannot find any delegate for checking if the request did succeed or not.

As I understand it `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` is only for receiving errors during the actual download.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yeah if your server is down then

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
 [error localizedDescription] 

}
```

method will return the possible reason & u can alert to user :)

Comment: Because I have added the  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error delegate method and running a NSURLConnection to a url with no connection doesn't give me any call to  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

Comment: then you have to work with apple's reachability classes :) it will let u know whether you are connected to network or not ..

Comment: So, are we talking about the same network? I have an Internet connection from my iphone, I want to check the reachability of the server. Is that what reachability are for?

Answer (score 0):

didFailWithError will be called if the connection cannot be made as well as if it's interrupted in download.

There's a good class called reachability that you can use to check whether a connection could be made before attempting to establish one (also how it can be made i.e via wifi, 3g etc) - you can find it [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `NSURLConnection` won't be initialized correctly in this case and you get `nil` value returned by the initializer.

Of course you can check device reachibility, but it shouldn't prevent you to check for `nil`.